# \includegraphics{} command was misplaced when compiling R sweave file to pdf through knitr

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

I was trying to generate two types of figures using a loop in an R Sweave document through knitr package.

Figure `p1` was saved by `png()` and `dev.off()` (this was actually done by a function from a third-party package, I simplified it here), and figure `p2` was generated by `ggplot`.

When I commented out the lines for saving `p1` and compiled, the PDF was created properly

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\begin{document}

<<echo=F, results='asis'>>=
library(ggplot2)
library(png)

f <- function(i){
   #png("p1.png") % these 3 lines for saving `p1`
   #plot(1,1)
   #dev.off()
   
   cat("\\begin{frame}[fragile]{",i, "}\n\n")
   p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
   print(p2)
   cat("\\end{frame}\n\n")
}

for(i in 1:2){
  f(i)
}  
@
\end{document}
```

along with a tex file like this,

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{ 1 }

\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/unnamed-chunk-1-1} 

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[fragile]{ 2 }

\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/unnamed-chunk-1-2} 

\end{frame}
```

But if i uncommented those lines, all but the last `\includegraphics` commands were misplaced.

```
\begin{frame}[fragile]{ 1 }

\end{frame}

\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/unnamed-chunk-1-1}   % <- this line was not contained within the frame enviroment any more
\begin{frame}[fragile]{ 2 }

\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]{figure/unnamed-chunk-1-2} 
\end{frame}
```

Could anyone please help me figure out what the problem is and how I can get the \includegraphics commands back to the correct places?

I really appreciate it.

Thanks